# Score isnt goint up by 2 when i answer right

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i need to make a exercise where i have to make sums. But when i answer the sum right the int score isnt going up by 2. Im pretty new to ASP/C# so sorry if im not that smart.

Here is the code i have:

```
int score = 0;
if (Int32.Parse(txt2.Text) == Int32.Parse(lbl1.Text) * Int32.Parse(lbl2.Text))
{
    lbl11.Visible = true;
    lbl11.Text = "Goed!";
    score = +2;
}
else
{
    lbl11.Visible = true;
    lbl11.Text = "Fout!";
    score = +0;
}
if (Int32.Parse(txt3.Text) == Int32.Parse(lbl3.Text) * Int32.Parse(lbl4.Text))
{
    lbl12.Visible = true;
    lbl12.Text = "Goed!";
    score = +2;
}
else
{
    lbl12.Visible = true;
    lbl12.Text = "Fout!";
    score = +0;
}
if (Int32.Parse(txt4.Text) == Int32.Parse(lbl5.Text) * Int32.Parse(lbl6.Text))
{
    lbl13.Visible = true;
    lbl13.Text = "Goed!";
    score = +2;
}
else
{
    lbl13.Visible = true;
    lbl13.Text = "Fout!";
    score = +0;
}
if (Int32.Parse(txt5.Text) == Int32.Parse(lbl7.Text) * Int32.Parse(lbl8.Text))
{
    lbl14.Visible = true;
    lbl14.Text = "Goed!";
    score = +2;
}
else
{
    lbl14.Visible = true;
    lbl14.Text = "Fout!";
    score = +0;
}
if (Int32.Parse(txt6.Text) == Int32.Parse(lbl9.Text) * Int32.Parse(lbl10.Text))
{
    lbl15.Visible = true;
    lbl15.Text = "Goed!";
    score = +2;
}
else
{
    lbl15.Visible = true;
    lbl15.Text = "Fout!";
    score = +0;
}
if(score >= 0)
{
    lblScore.Text = score.ToString();
}
else if(score <= 0)
{
    lblScore.Text = "0";
}
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: And what is your imput?

Comment: You need `score += 2;`, not `score = +2;` which just sets `score` to 2.

Comment: use score += 2 instead of score = +2;

Comment: Check your input, show some example values - check debug it, check the values of the text box, and labels are the ones you thought they were..

Comment: It would be a rare circumstance where both [tag:c#] and [tag:asp-classic] should be applied to the same question. asp-classic is for the pre-.NET era ASP, as opposed to [tag:asp.net] which is what I suspect you're using.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be using

```
score += 2;
```

instead of

```
score = +2;
```